# Can onDestroy() be called without onHandleWork() in JobIntentService?

Tags: android, service, nullpointerexception, android-lifecycle, jobintentservice

I am using `JobIntentService.enqueueWork()`

I would like to know if it's ever possible for the `onDestroy()` to be called even without `onHandleWork()` called in a JobIntentService.

Basically, what's the lifecycle of a JobIntentService. Is `onHandleWork()` guaranteed to be called at least once before `onDestroy()` gets invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of `JobIntentService` is different depending on the version of Android running on the target device (prior to API level 26, or API level 26 or higher).

However, generally you can assume that `onHandleWork()` is called at least once before `onDestroy()`. There would be no reason to start the `Service` if there was no work for it. Generally the `Service` would only be started when there is work in the queue, in which case `onHandleWork()` would be called immediately after the `Service` is started.